# How to place 3D object in vertical plane in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to place an 3D object on vertical plane with below code but it's not positioning properly. If anyone done with placing vertical object, need your help to do it.

```
@objc func addObjectToSceneView1(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){
let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

guard let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first, let anchor = hitTestResult.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
// create anchor and add to session and wait for callback
let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)} 

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
    // node for plane anchor
    let anchorNode = SCNNode()
    return anchorNode
} else {
    // must be node for most recent hit test
    guard let frameScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/frame/frame.scn"),
          let frameNode = frameScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "frame", recursively: true) else { return nil }
    return frameNode
}}
```

I am not getting what is wrong with this?

Comment: What do you mean by not placed properly

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya When I tap on detected vertical plane object will place but is not parallel to vertical plane. I am trying to change eularAngle of frameNode then it will not change, it is same as before changing eularAngle.

Comment: Code is correct but problem with position of object in scene file was wrong because of that object is not placing with correct position on vertical plane.